# Is there any way to publish posts bilingually in websites made by blogdown and Hugo Apero theme?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am a new user of Blogdown package and recently started blogging in my personal website. I am using Hugo-Apero theme. I published one English post and there is no problem. But, besides, I want my websites to be bilingual. For example; English and Persian. but unfortunately, I could not find a way to do that in Hugo-Apero theme. I know it is possible for simple hugo themes such as Lithium which is used in Yihui Xies's blog which is blogged in English and Chinese both, but I want that for Hugo Apero.
Any comments would really be appreciated.

I tried to do that by some codes in my yaml in my hugo apero theme, but I did not get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of Hugo Apero](https://github.com/hugo-apero/), it looks like it does not support multiple languages out of the box, as strings are hardcoded in English inside the theme templates.

You would have to:

1. search all english strings and replace them with [i18n markups](https://gohugo.io/functions/i18n/)
2. configure the different languages in the config file
3. create pages in the different languages in your content directory
4. if you want a language switcher in the menu bar, you would have to create it too.

More information here:
https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/

Comment: Thanks dear Jeremie. I did your suggestion and it worked in local version of my website.